# Import function vs turning it into custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this `ProductSearchContainer.js` file that it's getting too long to handle and maintain.

What it's responsible for:

- Doing network requests to get a list of products
- Filter that list with filters values it gets from URL query string and update state with the new filteredList
- It also holds functions to simulate the length of products on each filter before you click it. For example: a color filter with **Black(5)** indicating that you'll get 5 products if you click on **Black**.
- Along other functions

The file was getting too big (600+ lines) and I decide to move some pieces of logic to other files.

For each filter category (brand, price, rating, etc) I have two functions:

- 1 to apply the active filters (get a `list` and the `activeFilters` array and it returns a filtered list for those filters.
- 1 to simulate the next filter length (like I explained above on the colors example)

**Note:** You'll see below that they rely on state variable `activePriceFilters` but they don't call any React Hook in their execution.

---

**OPTION #1**

My 1st thought was to turn into a custom hook. So I did. And it works (see snippet below).

```
function usePriceFilter(activePriceFilters) {

  function applyPriceFilter(list, activePriceFilters) {
    console.log('I will get a list and return it filtered by activePriceFilters');
  }

  function simulateNextPriceFilter(list, someTestPriceFilter) {
    console.log('I will get a list and return the length of the filtered list by price');
  }

  return [applyPriceFilter,simulateNextPriceFilter];

}
```

And I consume by doing:

`const [applyPriceFilter,simulateNextPriceFilter] = usePriceFilter(activePriceFilters)`

I mean, my custom hook is basically a higher order function but I think it still qualifies as a custom hook:

[From React DOCS:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.

---

**OPTION #2**

But I guess I could also turn into a regular `.js` file, export both functions and just do the regular import on them. Like:

`import {applyPriceFilter,simulateNextPriceFilter} from './priceFilterHelpers`

---

**QUESTION:**

Is there a difference in functionaly or performance between the 2 approaches? Should I favor 1 instead of the other?

I think that the custom hook's is more readable, but is there anything else I'm gaining by doing this?

```js
function App() {

  const [activePriceFilters,setActivePriceFilters] = React.useState(['10to20','50+']);

  const [applyPriceFilter, simulateNextPriceFilter] = usePriceFilter(activePriceFilters);

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={applyPriceFilter}>Apply Price Filters</button>
      <button onClick={simulateNextPriceFilter}>Simulate Price Filter</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

}

function usePriceFilter(activePriceFilters) {

  function applyPriceFilter(list, activePriceFilters) {
    console.log('I will get a list and return it filtered by activePriceFilters');
  }

  function simulateNextPriceFilter(list, someTestPriceFilter) {
    console.log('I will get a list and return the length of the filtered list by price');
  }

  return [applyPriceFilter,simulateNextPriceFilter];

}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your option #2 would perform better, in theory, because you would (probably) write it such that those two functions only need to be instantiated once. In the custom hook version, the two functions, and the array that holds them, will be created on every render.

However, unless your case is **much, much, more computationally intensive** than your examples let on, the difference would **almost certainly be negligible**.

So it's really down to what kind of code you and the readers of your code find more legible. I personally fall on the side of the hooks.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think it's that intensive. l think I'll probably go with the hooks pattern too. It looks more "Reacty" than the other way. Those functions were being recreated on every render before I moved them to another file anyway. If any performance issues come in the future, I'll try to optmize somehow.